# How to specify each variable position (graph side) in a plot.loglm plot

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, graph-visualization, categorical-data

I have the following loglinear model.

```
library(MASS)
library(vcd)
## mosaic display for PreSex model
data("PreSex")
fm <- loglm(~ PremaritalSex * ExtramaritalSex * (Gender + MaritalStatus), 
            data = PreSex)

## visualize Pearson statistic
plot(fm, split_vertical = TRUE)
```

In the plot command, how can I specify which variables will be plotted in which plot sides 1 though 4? How does the plot.loglm command choose which variable will plot on which side?

**UPDATE #1 after pbible's answer:**

Just to make things clear another example. I have the model

```
data("PreSex")
fm <- loglm(~ PremaritalSex + ExtramaritalSex +Gender + MaritalStatus,data = PreSex)
plot(fm, split_vertical = TRUE)
```

which results in the mosaic plot [image]. In this plot the variables `PremaritalSex`, `MaritalStatus`, `ExtramaritalSex` and `Gender` are on sides 1,2,3 and 4 respectively.

**My question is:** How can I plot **the same loglinear model** (dont change the analysis) but have `Gender` on side 2 and `MaritalStatus` on side 4 of the resulting plot?

**Update #2:**
`mosaic` respects the order how the variables are entered (1st variable is in side 2, 2nd->side 3, 3rd->side 4, 4rth->side 1)

for example these 2 plots:

```
mosaic(~Gender+MaritalStatus +ExtramaritalSex + PremaritalSex  , data = PreSex, shade = T) # Gender is 1st variable in the model plotted in side 2, 
mosaic(~MaritalStatus + Gender+ExtramaritalSex + PremaritalSex  , data = PreSex, shade = T) # Gender is 2nd variable in the model plotted in side 3,
```

However `plot.loglm` does not respect the order of the variables entered. Regardless the order of the variables (additive model) it results in the same plot. For example the 2 plots obtained are the same

```
plot(loglm(~ Gender + MaritalStatus +ExtramaritalSex + PremaritalSex   , data = PreSex))
plot(loglm(~ MaritalStatus+Gender + ExtramaritalSex + PremaritalSex   , data = PreSex))
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How does plot change the model? The model is `fm` and has not changed (to my knowledge). But I see your point. Using condvars does change the way things look. Also have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/are_mosaic_plots_worthwhile.pdf). You may be able to produce a more informative diagram with bar graphs.

Comment: I see now. With your additive model condvars has no effect.

Comment: The problem is that while `mosaic` respects the order how the variables are entered (1st variable is size 2, 2nd->side 3, 3rd->side 4, 4rth->side 1), plot.loglm does not respect the order of the variables entered. Regardless the order of the variables (additive model) it results in the same plot. I was wondering if there is a way to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
After playing with it for a while, it seems you can accomplish your goal by permuting the array with `aperm`.

This seems to give you what you want:

```
fm <- loglm(~ PremaritalSex + ExtramaritalSex +Gender + MaritalStatus,data = aperm(PreSex,c(2,4,3,1)))
plot(fm, split_vertical = TRUE)
```

Here is the image:

[image]

It looks like mosaic enforces the structure of the array. Using array permutation allows you to modify this structure.

**Below: Part of an old answer, that may be helpful.**

I think what you may be looking for is `condvars` from the `mosaic` plot. You are plotting a `loglm` using the [vcd](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vcd/vcd.pdf) library. It uses `plot.loglm` which, in turn, can use `mosaic` or `assoc` (explained in the vcd manual).

After playing with it for a while, I found that you can use `condvars` to specify the conditional variables. Then `mosaic` will use these clues to reorder the plot.

Using the above commands:

```
plot(fm, split_vertical = TRUE)
```

[image: Using the above commands]

Changing the conditional variables with:

```
plot(fm, split_vertical = TRUE, condvars=c(2))
```

We get:

[image]

Have a look at the `mosaic` documentation from the vcd manual. This [post](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/vcd/docs/assoc.loglm) was also helpful. If you play with it you can get what you need. Also try using more than one conditional such as `c(2,3)` or something.

Comment: I can't understand the documentation of mosaic (I find it poorly specified). I am sure I don't want to condition on anything, I just want the plot reaaranged. I think on the example you mention somthing changes in the model, the boxes are not of the same size. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I am correct. Please see here http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vcd/vignettes/strucplot.pdf . The condvars conditions. What I need is just to reaarange the plot variable sides.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. From the reference you cite, it says "Here again, the sequence of conditioning levels is
restricted by the hierarchical structure of the structable object"(p14). The data frame you provide has its own conditioning based on the structure. The only way to rearrange the plot would be to change the structure. Are you asking for moving of labels?

Comment: Or do you mean the yes/no order?

Comment: Conditioning on a certain variable changes the analysis. What I want is just change the arrangement of the plot. Please see the my update of the question. Thanks for your time!